# responsive website

Tags: mobile, responsive

My website is : http://2stalbania.al/alltech/it/ and I would like to know how to make it responsive for mobile devices or tablets

Comment: Hi, please checkout http://w3schools.com for guides. The questions asked on StackExchange must be specific to WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it responsive by use of Bootstrap framework or by applying media queries into your CSS files.

Comment: thank you :) I tried with the media queries but it keeps showing messy ,I will try again